OpenCV gstreamer backend use GPU for H264 encoding
I have a gstreamer pipeline to encode frames in H264, it's working but I have a noticeable latency or delay of 2 seconds or more.
I've seen that my program is not using GPU, so maybe this is the main cause of that delay.
I have read that I can use vaapih264enc but seems to be not available in my gstreamer installation.
C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin>gst-inspect-1.0.exe vaapi
No such element or plugin 'vaapi'

How can I accelerate that pipeline or enable Hardware acceleration to reduce delay? Maybe using another encoding?
Source code example
import os
os.add_dll_directory("C:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\msvc_x86_64\\bin")
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

sourceUrl = "http://pendelcam.kip.uni-heidelberg.de/mjpg/video.mjpg"
command = "appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc key-int-max=30 speed-preset=veryfast tune=zerolatency bitrate=800 insert-vui=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=5004 host=127.0.0.1"

print(cv.getBuildInformation())

cap = cv.VideoCapture(sourceUrl)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("CAPTURE NOT OPENED")

fps = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
w = int(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
h = int(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
size = (w, h)
print(f"Size: {size}. FPS: {fps}")


writer = cv.VideoWriter(command, cv.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, fps, size, True)
if not writer.isOpened():
    print("WRITER NOT OPENED!!!!!")

if cap.isOpened() and writer.isOpened():
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Not Fram received")
            break
        writer.write(frame)
        cv.imshow("frame", frame)
        if cv.waitKey(1) > 0:
            break
    
    cap.release()
    writer.release()

Edit
I have seen that latency is caused by Vlc because of network-catching. I have set it to 500ms and seems to be better.
Also I have discovered qsvh264enc to use Intel UHD graphics for encoding.
What could be the best configuration for realtime or live pipeline with as less latency as possible?

I have edited my original post with some improvements that I have discovered. But I'm still need some help to improve more.
